# Angular 7 - tsconfig needs one file refresh to include external module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, tsconfig

I'm locked on a tsconfig problem.

My goal with my Angular 7 app is :

An app which can load-on-fly external modules. It allows external development to be include in the app without compiling the app again. It's an open marketplace.

For now, in prod mode, I'm loading UMD modules placed in assets with JIT compiler. (like thit : https://github.com/lmeijdam/angular-umd-dynamic-example). In dev mode, I would like to import dynamically my routes in lazy loading to exclude static module import (to avoid module import in prod) :

[image]

Modules are external from source so I added include in tsconfig :

[image]

My problem is here, when I launch the app with 'npm start', csv module is not include in the compilation (and no accessible in initDevRoutes()), but when I save a change in a file, the live reload compile the module and make it accessible...

[image]

What am I missing with ts config ?

**If someone has an other approch to do load-on-fly with angular 7 by adding module in assets after app build. Especially in AOT mode to erase JIT compiler from my app.**

Thanks !